# Shiny CSS: top-margin for tab-content excluding nav-list

Tags: css, r, shiny

In the following shiny ui and server code I would like to shift up the main page content in order to align it with the top of the selectInput element.

```
library(datasets)    

shinyUI(
      navbarPage("",

        tabPanel("Test1",
          selectInput("C", "", choices = c("A","B")),         
          navlistPanel("TITLE",
            tabPanel("A",
              column(6,tableOutput("view1"))
            ),
            tabPanel("B"),
            tabPanel("C"),
            "--",
            id="SideTabsA",well = TRUE, widths=c(2,10)
          )
        ),
        tabPanel("Test2",
          navlistPanel("TITLE",
            tabPanel("A",
              column(6,tableOutput("view2"))
            ),
            tabPanel("B"),
            tabPanel("C"),
            "--",
            id="SideTabs2",well = TRUE, widths=c(2,10)
          ), value = "res"
        ),id = "NAVITEMS"
      )
    )

    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

            output$view1 <- renderTable({
              head(rock, n = 20)
            })

            output$view2 <- renderTable({
              tail(rock, n = 20)
            })

    })
```

[image]
I suppose I have to use some css in order to achieve that but I cannot find how to do it. I tried:

```
.tab-content{
 margin-top:-50px;
}
```

but this will also shift the navlistPanel and selectInput elements.

UPDATE:

I also tried `.span10 {margin-top:-50px;}` but this shifts all .span10 elements and concequently the table in tab "Test2" which is not what I want. I would also expect to shift up 50px every .span10 element wherever it is used withing the app.

Would it be possible to give it an id somehow and shift only the desired span10 elements (i.e the ones that belong in a particular tabPanel)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally made it. It was really simple actually.

What had to be done is to put the tab-contents in div tag and assign a class. Then use this class in css.

The final ui.r code is:

```
 shinyUI( 
  navbarPage("",

    tabPanel("Test1",
    tags$head(tags$style( HTML(' .test1 .tab-content {margin-top:-50px;}'))),
      selectInput("C", "", choices = c("A","B")),         
      tags$div(class = "test1",
      navlistPanel("TITLE",
        tabPanel("A",
          column(6,tableOutput("view1"))
        ),
        tabPanel("B"),
        tabPanel("C"),
        "--",
        id="SideTabsA",well = TRUE, widths=c(2,10)
      )
    )),
    tabPanel("Test2",
      navlistPanel("TITLE",
        tabPanel("A",
          column(6,tableOutput("view2"))
        ),
        tabPanel("B"),
        tabPanel("C"),
        "--",
        id="SideTabs2",well = TRUE, widths=c(2,10)
      ), value = "res"
    ),id = "NAVITEMS"
  )
)
```